# How to send message to chat in IRC server?

Tags: java, irc, twitch

How to send message to chat in IRC server? 
[Here](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/IRC.md) is API server, and description how to connect to this server, but I don't know how to implement it in java.

At first I need to connect to his irc server with login and password. And then send message.
I found [PircBot](http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php) to connect to IRC server, but can't connect... to [this](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/IRC.md) API

1. How to connect to IRC server?
2. How to send message to IRC server?

I tried run in [Client](http://moepii.sourceforge.net/irclib/Client.java) for [this library](http://moepii.sourceforge.net/)

> java Client -server irc.twitch.tv:6667 -pass oauth:1vuwah03rawwpgs5u38y -nick nick -user nick -name nick -ssl

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/schwering/irc/lib
/IRCConnection
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.schwering.irc.lib.IRCConnection

        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: When you googled terms like "java IRC" or "java oAuth" what did you find? Hint: if you haven't done it already, you should be entering those search terms in your browser right about now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the PircBot documentation, you can see the bits you might need are:

to make the connection:
[http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/org/jibble/pircbot/PircBot.html#connect(java.lang.String](http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/org/jibble/pircbot/PircBot.html#connect%28java.lang.String), int)

to send the password:
[http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/org/jibble/pircbot/PircBot.html#sendRawLine(java.lang.String)](http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/org/jibble/pircbot/PircBot.html#sendRawLine%28java.lang.String%29)

I'm going to hazard a guess as I've never connected to twitch, but I'd imagine your connection lines would look like:

```
bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv",6667);
bot.sendRawLine("PASS oauth:twitch_oauth_token");
bot.sendRawLine("NICK yournickname");
```

edit:

and to answer the question in the title:

Once connected to the server, PircBot has a `sendMessage(String channel,String message)` method, which will, as you would expect, send a message to the channel.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code by C_STo, but it didn't work for me. This is the code that worked for me:

```
bot.connect("irc.chat.twitch.tv", 6667, "oauth:your_auth_code_here");
```

You provide an auth code as a parameter to connect method. This approach worked for me. But before that, you should have your name and user set. You do that with these commands:

```
bot.setName("your_username");
bot.setLogin("again_your_username");
```